# DateTime field not Updateable

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

Here's my code:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE tblTransactions SET Verifier = '" & strUserName & "' WHERE PatientAccountNumber = '" & Me.PatientAccountNumber & "'"                    
                    
strSQL = "UPDATE tblTransactions SET VerifierAssgnDate = #" & Date & "# WHERE PatientAccountNumber = '" & Me.PatientAccountNumber & "'"
```

"Verifier" updates fine, but "VerifierAssignDate" throws a "field not updateable" error.  It's a DateTime field.

Thanks!

Comment: You have two different database tags - which one is it?

Comment: I presume MS-Access is frontend for SQLServer. Why don't you update both fields in one SQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access type mismatch on date field with SQL Server express backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229173/access-type-mismatch-on-date-field-with-sql-server-express-backend)

Comment: You need to give the error you are receiving verbatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and should combine these (and `VerifierAssgnDate` was probably misspelled):

```vb
strSQL = "UPDATE tblTransactions " & _
    "SET Verifier = '" & strUserName & "', VerifierAssignDate = Date() " & _
    "WHERE PatientAccountNumber = '" & Me.PatientAccountNumber & "'"
```

Comment: Gustav - The misspelling was the culprit.  Thanks for the tip of combining the actions.

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to this board.  Done!